# ArcCatalog Representations Options Greyed Out

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arccatalog

I'm guessing this is a permissions error.   But everything I've tried enabling hasn't fixed the problem.  Does anyone know why this is greyed out or how to fix it?

This is in ArcCatalog.

[image: Options Greyed Out for Any Chosen Representation]

Comment: Are you in sde geodatabse? Maybe a lock? try remove all users and connect with the owner of this table.
Or view permissions in folder where the geodatabase is.

Comment: What user are you connecting as? Do you have DBO privilege? Only an owner can edit feature class properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this was caused by a schema lock (as suggested by Kirtep). I had edited the RuleID field separately in Python with an update cursor. Once I closed the Python window, I could edit the Representations again. So I suspect the feature class was used somewhere else (e.g., another application, another user), and had an active lock on it.